# Using video.js is it possible to get current HLS timestamp?

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

I have an application which is embedding a live stream in it. To cater for delays I'd like to know what is the current timestamp of the stream and compare it with the time on the server.

What I have tested up till now is checking the difference between the buffered time of the video with the current time of the video:

`player.bufferedEnd() - player.currentTime()`

However I'd like to compare the time with the server instead and to do so I need to get the timestamp of the last requested .ts file.

So, my question is using video.js, is there some sort of hook to get the timestamp of the last requested .ts file?

Video.js version: 7.4.1

Comment: Any answer yet?

Comment: Hi @Matthijs I will answer my own question as the answer is a bit long and won't fit here.

Answer (score 2):

I had managed to solve this issue, however please bear with me I don't remember where I had found the documentation for this bit of code.

In my case I was working in an Angular application, I had a video component responsible for loading a live stream with the use of video.js. Anyway let's see some code...

**Video initialisation**

```js
private videoInit() {
    this.player = videojs('video', {
        aspectRatio: this.videoStream.aspectRatio,
        controls: true,
        autoplay: false,
        muted: true,
        html5: {
            hls: {
                overrideNative: true
            }
        }
    });

    this.player.src({
        src: '://some-stream-url.com',
        type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
    });

    // on video play callback
    this.player.on('play', () => {
        this.saveHlsObject();
    });
}
```

**Save HLS Object**

```js
private saveHlsObject() {
    if (this.player !== undefined) {
        this.playerHls = (this.player.tech() as any).hls;

        // get and syncing server time...
        // make some request to get server time...
        // then calculate difference...
        this.diff = serverTime.getTime() - this.getVideoTime().getTime();
    }
}
```

**Get Timestamp of Video Segment**

```js
// access the player's playlists, get the last segment and extract time
// in my case URI of segments were for example: 1590763989033.ts
private getVideoTime(): Date {
    const targetMedia = this.playerHls.playlists.media();

    const lastSegment = targetMedia.segments[0];

    const uri: string = lastSegment.uri;
    const segmentTimestamp: number = +uri.substring(0, uri.length - 3);

    return new Date(segmentTimestamp);
}
```

So above the main point is the `getVideoTime` function. The time of a segment can be found in the segment URI, so that function extracts the time from the segment URI and then converts it to a Date object. Now to be honest, I don't know if this URI format is something that's a standard for HLS or something that was set for the particular stream I was connecting to. Hope this helps, and sorry I don't have any more specific information!

Comment: For analytics, I want to understand for which user which hls segments were downloaded. Is there any way I can get an event triggered whenever a segment (.ts) file is downloaded and get the name of that file. Then I will map that segment file name with user uuid and send to backend

Comment: @Yusuf I had worked on this a long time ago, and I don't have access to the code anymore. However, had a quick look at the documentation and there's a function which might help: `vhs.selectPlaylist` (https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming#vhsselectplaylist). Hope this helps! I'm no expert on video.js though I had only used it once a long time ago, so I might be wrong with my suggestion. I recommend consulting the documentation or try to find help via GitHub :)